# Easiest way to optimize app to different screen sizes in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I wanted to know what is the best way to optimize an app for different screen sizes in Xcode? I'm not using auto-layout.

In the beta&GM builds of Xcode 6 when I ran my app on the iPhone 6/6+ simulator everything sort of scaled automatically for the bigger screen size, but now in the final build, when I design an app with 4" storyboard, when I run on bigger screen sizes, the application remains in a 4" view in the top left of the screen.

I know that I can manually set and scale every element in code to fit to each screen size, but this method is very long and cumbersome and I don't think it's the optimal way to achieve it.

Is there any way to get that option from the beta builds back, or what is the best way to optimize my app to bigger screen sizes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to throw away your reason for not utilizing Auto-Layout and Size classes. These are beautiful design techniques and tackle this exact problem first hand.

Comment: Ok, and there is now way of automatically scaling everything like in the beta builds of Xcode 6?

Comment: When you say the beta builds of Xcode 6 automatically scaled everything what are you referring to? Auto-Layout existed in Xcode 6 beta and is the recommended way to handle multiple screen sizes and orientations. Universal storyboards and size classes with auto-layout have made this more simple than ever before and are extremely powerful once setup.